# Adding your YouTube subscriptions to Google Reader?

Tags: rss, google-reader, youtube

So I have a few subscriptions on my YouTube account and I would like to put an RSS feed that has all these subscriptions accumulated into my Google Reader account. Is it possible? I've been looking for some time but can't find an RSS feed for something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Go to https://www.youtube.com/account_sharing
- Check `Subscribe to a channel`
- Click `Save`

Then, either:

- Go to http://youtube.com/my_subscriptions and use your browser's RSS-finding features
- Or add this URL to your RSS reader, inserting your YouTube username:  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE/newsubscriptionvideos?client=ytapi-youtube-user&v=2

Comment: Well, this almost worked... After I just grabbed the RSS URL and pasted it into google reader... nothing would show up. So what I had to do is after I clicked to RSS button I chose "Subscribe to this feed using - Google" and then you again get two options - "add to google homepage" and "add to google reader". You choose the second one and that's it. Thank you iuri!

Comment: I just had to go here youtube.com/my_subscriptions and press the RSS icon in the browser bar.

Comment: "Yes, allow a selected set of my activities to be viewable" isn't there any more.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of built in RSS tools from Youtube [(see here)](http://www.youtube.com/rssls), but there is none for Subscriptions. You could make your own subscriptions by just subscribing to every single user's RSS feed in Google Reader. That's not handy if you have many subscriptions, though.